# Lyapunov function for a damped pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, stability-in-odes

The question is about damped pendulum. There are two statements I don't understand or I'm not sure if my justification for them is correct. Could you say if I'm right?

The example is from a German book, *Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen und dynamische Systeme*, by Mathias Wilke & Jan Prüss. I've translated the question, but [the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Bsh.jpg) is here if you want to see it.

A damped pendulum has an equation
$$V(u,v)=\frac12v^2+w^2(1-\cos u)$$

which is a Lyapunov function of
$$\cases{u'=v  & \cr v'=-\alpha v-w^2\sin u} \alpha, w\ge 0$$

1. It is written that $V(u,v)\to\infty$ for $|v|\to\infty$ which implies $|u'(t)|=|v(t)|\le M$. Is it because otherwise $V$ would be not decreasing?
2. $|u''(t)|\le M$ and multiplying it with the differential equation gives $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty u'(t)dt<\infty$. But why $u''+\alpha u'+w^2\sin u=0$ is true? Multiplying it with $u'$ gives $$u'\implies u'u''+u'\alpha u'+u'w^2\sin u=0\iff u''u'+u'w^2\sin u=-\alpha(u')^2$$

and integrating
$$\int_0^\infty u''u'+u'w^2\sin u=\int_0^\infty-\alpha(u')^2.$$

The LHS now is
$$\underbrace{\displaystyle\frac{(u')^2}{2}\Bigg|_{0}^{\infty}}_{<\infty\text{by (1)}}+\underbrace{\int u'w^2\sin u}_{\text{how to show $<\infty$}}\implies\int-\alpha(u')^2<\infty\implies\int_0^\infty u'(t)dt<\infty$$

Comment: At least, $\int_0^{\infty} \sin u(x) \,dx < +\infty$ is incorrect, in general. (Check, for instance, the case $u(x) \equiv 1$).

Comment: Oops, you just missed $u'$ in the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \sin u$.

Comment: You also forgot to write the power 2 of $u'$.  However, you arguments are correct.

Comment: @Voliar the arguments (1) (2) are correct, but not the justification then

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Voliar I mean $(1)$ and $(2)$ are given from the book. Here I tried to prove them, but obviously failed

Comment: $u' \sin u = -(\cos u)'$. Therefore, $\int u' \sin u = - \int (\cos u)' = \cos u |_0^{\infty} \in [-1, 1]$ - finite.

Comment: a translation from german of the linked text would really help future readers